# Adding more than two address lines to a document of class res

Tags: line-breaking, document-classes, resume

I'm using the [res9b](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) template and I'm trying to figure out how to add one more address line. I tried using "\\" but the output is a comma separated list instead of a line break.

Comment: Try: `\address{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{1985  Storm Lane, Troy, NY 12180\\ 1985  Storm Lane, Troy, NY 12180}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the content of the address in a `\parbox{<width>}{<content>}` can be a quick hack. Something like the following may help:

```
\address{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{%
        1985  Storm Lane, Troy, NY 12180\\ %
        1985  Storm Lane, Troy, NY 12180}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Now I wonder if there is a way to indent the lines to the right. When using "\hfil" or "\hfill" on each line, it somehow indents only the first one. Thanks!

Comment: @Milka Which line are you talking about?

Comment: When I try to indent it this way: `\address{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{\hfill line 1\\ \hfill line 2\\ \hfill line 3}` only line 1 gets indented.

Comment: @Milka Add a `\null` in front of the last two `\hfill`. That is, `\address{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{\hfill line 1\\ \null\hfill line 2\\ \null\hfill line 3}}`

Comment: @Milka An `\hbox{}` in the place of `\null` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Under the `line` class option for [`res`](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls), `\\` is redefined to be `,` . This can be seen when viewing the definition of `\@linename`, used to print the resume title under the `line` option:

```
\def\@linename{\begingroup
  \def\\{, }
  {\namefont\@name}
  \vskip 2pt
  \fullline
  \vskip 2pt
  % where do you live?
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{%
    % do nothing
  }{%
    \leavevmode\hbox to \textwidth
      {\hfill\vbox{\hbox{\@addressone}
           \hbox{\@addresstwo}
          }%
      }\par
  }
\endgroup}
```

Also note that `\@addressone` (the first address that you store using `\address`) is set in a box that doesn't parse `\\` the way you think it should. We need a little more work to restore the `tabular`-like definition.

The actual "title print macro" `\print@name` is set at document load to `\@linename`, so any changes should be performed on `\print@name`. You can patch `\print@name` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) or directly with a redefinition) and remove the scope of this redefinition. Using `etoolbox`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\print@name}{\endgroup}{\relax}{}{} % Remove scope
\patchcmd{\print@name}{\@ifundefined}{\endgroup\@ifundefined}{}{}% Insert end-of-scope earlier
\patchcmd{\print@name}{\@addressone}{\@tablebox{\@addressone}}{}{}% Insert \@addressone in tabular (box)
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, guess its more than a hack like mine :-)